# Texreg is not showing me Rsquare and adjusted Rsquare

Tags: r, latex, lme4, texreg

I have a model:

mixed.lmer.str.df <- lmer(StroopEffort ~ Temperature + RH + sex + (1|Participant) + (1|order), data = df)

And I am using LmerTest. The summary is as follow:

[Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESjzy.png)
I want to export it to Latex,
The problem is that unlike what I can see on different examples, and even when I make all arguments "True", still it is not showing, conditional and adjusted Rsquare, although I can see them when I use Tab_Model.

the code:

mixed.lmer.str.df <- lmer(StroopEffort ~ Temperature + RH + sex +(1|Participant)+ (1|order), data = df)

summary(mixed.lmer.str.df)

tab_model(mixed.lmer.str.df)

texreg(mixed.lmer.str.df,booktabs = TRUE, include.aic = TRUE, include.bic = TRUE,
include.dic = TRUE ,include.deviance = TRUE, include.loglik = TRUE,include.nobs = TRUE,include.groups = TRUE,include.variance = TRUE)

[texreg output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKxTc.png)

Could you please advise what is the problem?

Comment: Can you share your `texreg::extract()` code?

Comment: You need to show the code that generated the output.

Comment: mixed.lmer.str.df <- lmer(StroopEffort ~ Temperature + RH + sex +(1|Participant)+ (1|order), data = df)
summary(mixed.lmer.str.df)
tab_model(mixed.lmer.str.df)
texreg(mixed.lmer.str.df,booktabs = TRUE, include.aic = TRUE, include.bic = TRUE,
include.dic = TRUE ,include.deviance = TRUE, include.loglik = TRUE,include.nobs = TRUE,include.groups = TRUE,include.variance = TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

See `texreg`'s implementation of `extract.lme4()` [here](https://github.com/leifeld/texreg/blob/92e393131f5d6c0f75fbfc3934567d36032e626a/R/extract.R#L3992).

The implementation does not handle an `include.rsquared` argument so the reason you are likely not seeing a change in the output is that it is silently ignoring that argument.

Comment: Thanks Josh. True , I had not noticed that; but now I tried other arguments and they are not showing me R2 and adj R2 as well.